# problem in creating GUI for upload & download file by Oracle forms

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle9i, oracleforms

I want to create a GUI in Oracle form 10g, the purpose of creating this page is :

-user able to upload & see uploaded file(upload into ftp)

-User able to remove his file(from ftp)

-user able to Download file(from FTP)

-this GUI should able transfer big files also(around 12M)

I am new in Oracle forms 10g because of that before I start, I guess it would be good I ask my question here & get help.

currently we use Oracle form 6i,and we use batch file & ftp service for moving file manually but by increasing our branch I guess if we do these work automatically we can decrease our faults. also our branch now copy their file manually in ftp.

I am looking for design something like drag & drop for upload files. What is new services from oracle to make me easier to connect via ftp & make upload, download/create folder (to/from/in ftp)?

I hope u have good idea for sharing with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not the first to ask: see for example http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=689655. However that method (using WebUtil to get the file, then use UTL_FTP on the server to send it) seems to require two transfers - from the client to the database server, then FTP from the database server.

A better method might be a Java Bean, see http://forms.pjc.bean.over-blog.com/article-23800297.html

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey,I would like to create something like ur second link, I hope it will help me so much...thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the ultimate destination of the file is an FTP server, then you are best off using a dedicated FTP client, rather than Oracle Forms. Also, FTP is an insecure protocol, so I'd be switching to SFTP (FTP using SSH) or FTPS (FTP over SSL).